# How to prevent video lag while watching video (On VLC and Totem)?

Tags: sound, video, vlc, video-player, totem

Thanks if you're reading this.
First of all, I got to say that I  have Ubuntu 12.10 (I had 12.04 before, and it was playing videos great, but then I upgraded it).

Ok, so, I'm watching some video and then it just stops moving but the audio keeps up. The video keeps running when I move the mouse.

I tried playing a video on a Ubuntu 13.04 liveCD, but I can't install anything and the default video player needs codecs to play .flv videos.

Comment: You can try to put Ubuntu on USB stick, then install ubuntu-restricted-extras package on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large enough flash drive (2gb would be enough) you could turn it into a persistant install which would allow you to make changes to the installation on the USB such as installing the codecs you need or saving your preferences. UNetbootin has this feature when you create a new liveUSB.